# [INQUIRY ]JavaScript - Variable Initilization

Tags: javascript

```js
function calculateArea(r){
  var area;
  if (r<=0){
    return 0;
  } else {
    area=Math.PI*r*r; 
    return area; 
  }
}

var radius = 5.2; 
var theArea=calculateArea(radius);
console.log("Area = " + theArea);
```

New here, please let me know if I have posted incorrectly.

If the initialization of a variable is a function. Does the function execute automatically?
For instance, see my code below. I get the desired output in the console log.
Had I not included this function in the variable, would it have still ran?

```
   function calculateArea(r){
  var area;
  if (r<=0){
    return 0;
  } else {
    area=Math.PI*r*r; 
    return area; 
  }
}

var radius = 5.2; 
var theArea=calculateArea(radius);
console.log("Area = " + theArea);
```

EDIT: Think I've got my head wrapped around this not. Thank you all!

Comment: Seems like you could probably just test it and see, right?

Comment: The initialization of the `theArea` variable is not a function, but rather a function's return value. There is a big distinction.  Nothing out of the ordinary is going on here. You call a function, store the result in a variable, then print the variable. "Had I not included this function in the variable, would it have still ran?" What are you referring to? You aren't including a function in any variables here. You just just calling a function and storing the result in a variable.

Comment: Well, I have and, yes, I can see it in console log. But if I don't run the function by way of variable initialization, will the function still run in the background or must it be called manually?

Comment: The `calculateArea` function as you've defined will not run by itself. It is simply defined. It only runs when you call it, such as `calculateArea(radius)`

Comment: And it's being called because that variable theArea must be initialized?

Comment: No, it's being called because `calculateArea(radius)` calls the function. It has nothing to do with storing the result in a variable.

Comment: Side note - if you are ever curious whether or not a function is being called, and when it is being called, you could always just `console.log` a value within the function. If you don't see your manual `console.log` result, it's fairly safe to assume the function was never executed.

Comment: Not relevan to the question, but your function is actually just that `function calculateArea(r){ return r<=0?0:Math.PI*r*r; }`

Answer (score 1):

No, defining a function doesn't run it automatically. (After all, if it requires an argument, like `r` in your case, what would that `r` be?)

You will need to call the function (`calculateArea(1)`) for it to be run, but you don't need to assign the return value to a variable (`area = calculateArea(1)`) for that to happen.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation!

Answer (score 1):

if you call it without any arguments

```
calculateArea()
```

`r` will be undefined, leading to `Math.PI * r * r = number * undefined = NaN`

and if you never used this

```
var theArea=calculateArea(radius);
```

then the function won't be executed automatically